# Indenting "read" input when it contains multiple lines

Tags: bash

I have a `read` command in a bash script whose input defines an array. The input will frequently be copy/pasted data that contains multiple lines. Each line in the multi-line input is correctly captured and added to the array as separate elements, but I'd like to indent each line with a `>` prefix in the terminal window when it is pasted in.

This is for bash v3 running on macOS. I've attempted various flavors of the `read` command, but couldn't come across anything that worked.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Provide inputs:"
until [[ "$message" = "three" ]]; do
    read -p "> " message
    myArray+=($message) #Input added to array for later processing
done
```

Manually typed inputs look like this:

```
Provide inputs:
> one
> two
> three
```

But a copy/pasted multi-line input look like this:

```
Provide inputs:
> one
two
three
> >
```

The desired result is for the copy/pasted multi-line input to look identical to the manually entered inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is with the way read works. Read echos back keystrokes and I think perhaps because of stdout buffer it is writtern before the echo statements are flushed.

Using a combo of echo command and the `-e` argument to read (interactive) fixes this in my testing.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Provide inputs:"
until [[ "$message" = "three" ]]; do
    echo -ne "> "
    read -e message
    myArray+=($message) #Input added to array for later processing
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: I understand, see new answer

Answer (score 0):

(Answer changed after explanation of OP what he wants)
The screen will look identical when the input is entered line-by-line and when entered after copy-paste of multiple lines when you remove the `>` (I added `-r` in view of special characters).

```
until [[ "$message" = "three" ]]; do
   read -r message
   myArray+=("$message")
done
```

When you want to see the `>`, you can use the ugly

```
printf "> "
until [[ "$message" = "three" ]]; do
   read -rs message
   printf "%s\n> " "${message}"
   myArray+=("$message")
done
```

In this case the input is only shown after an `Enter`, so this seems worse.

Comment: To clarify, I don't actually want "> " included in the array elements, only printed to the screen during input.

Comment: In that case I do not understand your question. You can use `myArray+=("   $message")` for indenting some spaces. Can you add the desired output in your question?

Comment: I tried to edit my question yesterday to better clarify. Perhaps it's still not there. The "output" desired has nothing to do with storing the inputs as array elements (which is already working). What I would like is for when a user has multiple lines in their clipboard, and they paste their input at the prompt, for each line, not just the first, to include "> " on the screen; identical to if each line was entered individually.

Comment: I modified my answer, but I think it is not what you want. I don't know a better solution.

Comment: Hey no worries. Thanks for the suggestions! I'll keep after it.